# Change to brightness of screen in iPhone

Tags: ios4

I am developing an iBook like application where user can change the brightness of the app by selection value of UISlider. I have done googling but I found the method     GSEventSetBacklightLevel(1.0f); and this is undocumented and private. So I can not use this method in application. Please help me to provide brightness functionality in the application.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936999/iphone-how-can-we-programmatically-change-the-brightness-of-the-screen/8937010#8937010

Answer (score 3):

```
NSLog(@"brightness : %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]);
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:.2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that apps like Instapaper do a "software" brightness by changing the background between white and some shade of grey.  The iBook app is probably therefore using some private API methods.  There is of course display brightness in the Preferences app, which applies across all apps.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Even KOBO is also providing the same brightness in their book reading application.