# How can we programmatically change the brightness of the iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

How can I change the brightness of the screen programmatically using iPhone SDK?

Comment: Seeing as that is a part of official SDK, I suggest you check your sources. http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: yourvalue];
```

Requires iOS 5.0 or later. *yourvalue* is a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept the answer if it is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Wouldn't this get you kicked off the App Store though?

Comment: It's a perfectly legal API call. I can't see a reason why there should be any problem with it.

Comment: @Robse you may store the original brightness using `UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness` first then restore the brightness using this value at a later stage.

Comment: I add this line `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: 0.6f];` to `viewDidAppear` and nothing happened.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE**: For Swift 3

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = YourBrightnessValue
```

Here's the swift answer to perform this

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = YourBrightnessValue
```

YourBrightnessValue is a float between `0.0` and `1.0`

Comment: to request current brightness:  let brillo : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.brightness

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems with changing the screen brightness in viewDidLoad/viewWillDisappear so I created a singleton class to handle all the action. This is how I do it:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class ScreenBrightnessHelper {

    private var timer: Timer?
    private var brightness: CGFloat?
    private var isBrighteningScreen = false
    private var isDarkeningScreen = false

    private init() { }

    static let shared = ScreenBrightnessHelper()

    func brightenDisplay() {
        resetTimer()
        isBrighteningScreen = true
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *), timer == nil {
            brightness = UIScreen.main.brightness
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                UIScreen.main.brightness = UIScreen.main.brightness + 0.01
                if UIScreen.main.brightness > 0.99 || !self.isBrighteningScreen {
                    self.resetTimer()
                }
            }
        }
        timer?.fire()
    }

    func darkenDisplay() {
        resetTimer()
        isDarkeningScreen = true
        guard let brightness = brightness else {
            return
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *), timer == nil {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                UIScreen.main.brightness = UIScreen.main.brightness - 0.01

                if UIScreen.main.brightness < brightness || !self.isDarkeningScreen {
                    self.resetTimer()
                    self.brightness = nil
                }
            }
            timer?.fire()
        }
    }

    private func resetTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        isBrighteningScreen = false
        isDarkeningScreen = false
    }
}
```