# Changing the brightness of iphone screen programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way of adjusting the screen brightness programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779667/is-there-a-way-of-adjusting-the-screen-brightness-programmatically)
>   [iPhone: How can we programmatically change the brightness of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936999/iphone-how-can-we-programmatically-change-the-brightness-of-the-screen)

How can we change (Decrease and increase) Brightness of the iphone screen programmatically by touch events?

Comment: i would suggest going through this link, it will guide u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/change-backlight-brightness-on-iphone-programmatically

Comment: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:float];`

Answer (score 1):

A Float value of 0 - 1 can be used to do this, for example:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: 0.5f];
```